# Disadvantages of an encrypted /boot?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, encryption

Been doing a lot of reading on Linux encryption techniques, and one that I've come across is encrypting the /boot directory by keeping it on the same partition as the root. I recall reading somewhere that if you encrypted your /boot, you would need to modify GRUB or something every time your system updated. Can't remember where I read that, so not 100% sure if it's true or not. Are there any other disadvantages of having /boot encrypted?

Comment: See https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dm-crypt/Encrypting_an_entire_system#Encrypted_boot_partition_.28GRUB.29

Comment: @Panther I've seen some of your other posts and you seem to be knowledgeable with LUKS encryption. In your opinion, is encrypting /boot worth the hassle? Trying to get it setup with a keyfile so I only need to enter my password once has been a major pain. I'm considering just leaving /boot unencrypted and moving on. My laptop stays on a desk 99% of the time, so the risk of someone getting a hold of it is pretty low. From what I've read, even if someone were to steal it and mess with my /boot, they wouldn't be able to get the rest of my data without me entering the password, right?

Comment: The risk of an unencrypted /boot partition would be the evil maid scenario - ie someone installs a custom kernel or custom initrd , they then , in theory, could obtain you password or data once you boot. My /boot is not encypted and I will leave it that way. I will probably test an encrypted /boot in a VM and if it works well, next time I install I will use it so personally, with your current situation, go ahead and try to encrypt /boot. If you have a problem, post the error or a description of your problem and we will try to help.

Comment: @Panther But the boot loader ***has*** to be accessible to the UEFI firmware. Thus a shim loader that can decrypt the `/boot` has to be in the UEFI partition. An attacker can replace this with a version that logs the passphrase. Secure boot will mitigate this, but secure boot will also mitigate it with an cleartext `/boot`, as the kernel will be validated...

Answer (score 1):

Currently, at least on OpenSuse Tumbleweed, you're required to enter the LUKS password twice: once to decrypt /boot and once to decrypt your other partitions (assuming you use the same password for all partitions).

In the early unlock, Grub2 also defaults to a US English keyboard layout, so you can't type in Dvorak or German or whatever your normal layout may be. Customizing that layout seems to involve a bit of work.

With systemd-boot on Pop_OS, you only need to enter the LUKS password once with an encrypted /boot.